# Mozilla Rhino NativeArray.add() is throwing an error - always

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm looking for build a javascript array in java using mozilla rhino `NativeArray` class,
however when I try to add elements to `NativeArray` a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown.

here is my code:

```
NativeArray array=new NativeArray(1);
array.add("cccc");
```

and here is the error I'm receiving:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.add(NativeArray.java:1826)
```

If I create the NativeArray with a java array from the begining everything is working great.

```
String[] str=new String[2];
str[0]="aaaa";
str[1]="bbbb";
NativeArray array=new NativeArray(str);
```

I was looking through NativeArray source code and I was surprised to see that the add method always throws an error
here is the source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray.java#1825

**Note: I'm using mozilla rhino 1.7R4 which is the latest version so far**

It this a bug from mozilla rhino or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a requirement to use Rhino ? There are others way to interact with JS in Java that are more stable than Rhino.

Comment: @JulienS. can you give me more detales?

Answer (score 1):

My original answer (below) is incorrect. "Native" here means "native JavaScript array". Why `.add()` is not implemented, given that the implementation extends the `List` interface, I can't say. It is possible however to use the JavaScript means for extending the array (`.push()` etc).

---

It doesn't make sense to implement `.add()` for a native array. They're fixed-length arrays, and the length is constant.

Note that `.add()` is marked as an "optional operation" in the `java.util.Collection` interface.

Comment: yes.. you're right. I was thinking this is more like ArrayList

Comment: "They're fixed-length arrays". Are you sure? It seems to me `NativeArray` is JS array, which is not fixed size. It implements `push` using its `js_push` members, beside other. Fixed-length representation is `NativeJavaArray`.

Comment: @Suma you are correct. The non-implementation of `.add()` must be some design decision that may be obscure, but it's plain as day that they didn't want that behavior for the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code instead of add():

```
NativeArray array;
array.put(array.size(), array, result);
```